# Why does multiple ejb jars in an EAR share the same classloader whereas each WAR gets its own classloader?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, classloader

Well, title pretty much says it :). From whatever I have read i know by design EJBs share a single classloader but I am willing to understand the reason behind it. Would appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Each WAR is a standalone module. Each JAR in the root of an EAR aswell as the WAR file inside are related modules. Thus it makes sense for them to use the same classloader. Sharing class loader between multiple WAR files would not be feasable.

Comment: What do you mean by related modules? And as per my understanding other jars at the root of the EAR are loaded by EAR classloader. But All the EJBS are loaded by a separate EJB classloader. So other jar at the root of EAR and ejbs do not share the same classloader

Comment: I think I missunderstood your question a bit, I don't quite feel confident to answer it correctly.